# how to loop trough an objects and dynamically push items to array in javasript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am a python dev for the most part and im trying to solve a quick problem using `javasript`. I have the following data:

```
data = {
  name: "james_0",
  hobby: "dev_0",
  country: "usa",
}
```

i want to make sure each item included in the objects data which values ends with "_0" is push to an objects, then all those fields get pushed to an array

## expected results

```
data = [{name: "james_0", hobby: "dev_0"}]
```

I tried the following codes but seem to be missing something

```
const result = []

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  if (value.endsWith("_0")) {

    result.push({key: value}) <== Something seem to be missing around this
  }
  
}

console.log("result", result)
```

Comment: Can you clarify why your expected result is an array? It looks like it will always have just one item wrapping the transformed object, or is data actually an array of objects?

Comment: "*all those fields get pushed to an array*" - this doesn't make sense. Your expected result has an array containing exactly one object - so why use an array? Did you want to get one *object* back with the properties matching your filter? Or actually an array of key-value-pairs matching your filter? Or something else?

Comment: @Bergi the expect results line is how expecting the result of the transformation...

Comment: @NickParsons i have one input which is the object `data` and one expected results, which should be output result...forget about the the codes i used to solve it...

Comment: Your code, as posted in the question, works fine - edit, never mind, just noticed what your expected resutl is

Comment: @JaromandaX it does not give me the expected result

Comment: Yeah, I know ... you expect an array with a single object - why do you want an array with a single object?

Comment: @JohnD Can you give a few more examples of possible input and the respective output? Especially where the input has no properties with names ending in `_0`?

Comment: try `result[0] = {...result[0], ...items};` instead of pushing to the array, since you only want a single item in your array - that will give you exactly the result you expect

Comment: @JaromandaX do you mind posting the solution im having hard time to follow your suggestion, thanks

Comment: replace `result.push(items)` with `result[0] = {...result[0], ...items};` - that's all I'd say in a solution, so, I'm not posting that as a solution

Comment: The main reason I won't post that as a solution is because it's not the best way to do what you want

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, i figured...i have to figure out to make that happen anyway

Comment: Anyway - I've told you how to make it happen - change that one line and you'll get the result you need

Comment: or replace all the code with this one line `const result = [Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).filter(([, value]) => value.endsWith("_0")))];`

Comment: @JaromandaX someone posted the solution below, approved!

Comment: @JohnD - yes, they did, overcomplicated, but they did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = {
  name: "james_0",
  hobby: "dev_0",
  country: "usa",
}


function deleteNonIncluding (data = {}){
  const values = Object.values(data).filter(el => el.includes("_0"))
  
  const objectValues = Object.keys(data);
  
  
    const newObject = values.reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
  return {...accumulator, [objectValues[index]]: value};
}, {});
  
  return [newObject]
}

const newArray = deleteNonIncluding(data);

console.log(newArray)
```

Is this what you needed? It was kinda confusing following your question.

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong. Try adding another property after `country` that matches the filter and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array of entries via `Object.entries()`
2. Filter the values by their suffix
3. Re-create an object using `Object.fromEntries()`
4. Wrap the result in an array for some reason

```js
const data = {
  name: "james_0",
  hobby: "dev_0",
  country: "usa",
};

const result = [
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).filter(([_, value]) => value.endsWith("_0"))
  ),
];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: FYI - `[_, value]` can be `[, value]` to save a byte :D

Comment: do you mind showing the solution with an if statement `if (value.endsWith("_0")) {` im curious, if its not too much to ask

Comment: why would you use an `if` statement for this code, @JohnD - makes zero sense - you didn't ask the answer you accepted to use an `if` ... so why this one?

Comment: well i was just curious

Comment: @JohnD I see no reason to use an `if`. In fact, code that uses `if (someBooleanResult) return true; else return false;` is in my opinion a [code smell](https://dev.to/mcsee/code-smell-115-return-true-3gn4)

Comment: @JaromandaX _"save a byte"_... C# habits die hard